# How can I make a modal window(url) refresh to another modal window(url) via facebox

Tags: jquery, html, modal-dialog, thickbox, facebox

This is ultimately what I want to achieve.

User clicks on Page1

Modal window opens.

User clicks on Page2

Modal window refreshes to that page.

/////

But this is what happens

User clicks on Page1

Modal window opens.

User clicks on Page2

Page changes to index2.html.

Comment: is the link to page2 in de modal window?

Comment: Yes it is in the modal window.

Answer (score 0):

User clicks on "Page1" and page1 opens.
In page1 the user clicks on "refresh parent" button. The button then activates the following javascript command:

```
window.opener.location.reload(true);
```

window.opener referes to the parent page and location.reload(true) refreshes the page.